# What is the appropriate location for custom systemd service files?

Tags: fedora, systemd, services

I have many custom service files that I control with systemctl and up until today I have been putting these .service files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, however today I obtained a new program and it automatically created the .service file in a location I didn't think of - `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Is this where I should have been putting the service files I have created myself? Both directories appear to work, so ultimately I know it doesn't make a difference, but what does convention dictate? Is there a more correct location to have these custom service files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The convention is that `/usr/lib` is for files installed by the system, and `/etc` is for local configuration.